# Hibernate 3 hql query for joining 2 table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to execute following sql query

```
SELECT * FROM users u JOIN `friendship` f ON u.id = f.f_uid WHERE f.u_uid = 118 AND u.lastDataFetched >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)) order by f.mutual_friendship_count
```

How do I write hql query for this with hibernate 3.0

I have written like this

```
String[] parameterName={"usersByUUid","inthepastday"};
Object[] paramValues = {user,"7"};
List<Friendship> friendshipFriend  = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(" from Users u JOIN Friendship f on  u.id = f.f_uid where f.u_uid = :usersByUUid and date_sub(now(),interval :inthepastday day) >=u.lastDataFetched  order by f.mutual_friendship_count ", parameterName,paramValues);
```

but it shows hql syntax error

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use java code and create needed date (today date - 7 days) using `java.util.Calendar` or `JodaTime`. Then pass it into hql:

   `and :date7DaysAgo >= u.lastDataFetched`
2. Another way is to use Native query, so you can write pure SQL. Just add annotation `@NamedNativeQuery`.
   Then call it via `getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("nameOfYourNamedQuery");`